# "Serial voting was reversed"?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I don't even understand what happened or what's going on.

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

For starters:

- What is serial voting?
- It cost me points.. Did I break rules of this site or something like that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yesterday you received a bunch of votes cast in a very short timeframe. Such anomalous patterns are reversed automatically every night.

If you used a sock puppet to upvote your own account that way, you did something wrong. If the votes were cast by a different user, you did nothing wrong and don't need to worry about anything.

Comment: If the votes were cast by a different user, *that user* did something wrong. It happens every now and then, just as random downvotes for no apparent reason happen.

Comment: You did nothing wrong _if_ you didn't ask the other person to vote on your questions and answers.

Answer (score 5):

Serial voting happens when people vote on many posts by the same author. This is an abuse of the voting system, so the votes have been removed. Since those were up votes on posts by you, you lost reputation, but it's reputation you never really *earned* to begin with. :)

Answer (score 3):

"Serial voting" occurs when somebody casts a large number of votes on the posts of a single user in a short period of time; that is to say, votes for the user, without regard for the content posted.

There are scripts in place which automatically detect this behavior, and undo the votes in question. This is what happened to you. You did nothing wrong, though somebody else might have.